# Can SAP GUI interactions be captured without a VBS recorder

Tags: python, sap-gui

Is it achievable to capture interactions with SAP GUI elements without relying on a VBS recorder, and are there any integrated SAP GUI components designed for this specific purpose?

Obs: Not recorder screen

```
import win32com.client

# Conectando ao SAPGUI
SAPGuiAuto = win32com.client.GetObject("SAPGUI")
if not type(SAPGuiAuto) == win32com.client.CDispatch:
    raise Exception("Não foi possível acessar o SAPGUI.")

application = SAPGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
if not type(application) == win32com.client.CDispatch:
    raise Exception("Não foi possível acessar a aplicação SAP.")

# Ativar a janela do SAPGUI (pode variar dependendo da configuração)
connection = application.Connections(0)  # Pode precisar ajustar o índice da conexão
session = connection.Sessions(0)  # Pode precisar ajustar o índice da sessão

>>>>> Get interaction <<<<
```

Comment: No idea what "VBS recorder" means? If you are talking about the well-known Official SAP GUI Scripting Recorder, the answer is yes, you may create your own custom program and use the recording methods of SAP GUI Scripting.

Comment: Yes, the "VBS recorder" refers to the official script recorder of the SAP GUI. However, if you wish to avoid using this recorder and are looking for an alternative, it is possible to use internal methods of the SAPGui object to record interactions between the user and the system. By doing this, you can have more control over the recording process and customize it according to your specific needs.

Comment: Here, did you answer your own question? NB: thank you, I agree, I'm sure it's possible because I did my own recorder.

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I expressed myself poorly. I would like to create my own recorder, exactly that Sandra Rossi.

Comment: Sorry, but Stack Overflow is not to provide opinion/recommendations/links (see the Help center). You should come with precise questions which inspire precise answers. You can ask these broad questions on any SAP forum. Just to help you, the public SAP GUI Scripting documentation explains everything, the most interesting object is `GuiSession` and its members `record` and `change`. Good luck in your search!